# Join array and wrap every element with Guava Joiner

Tags: java, guava

I have array of Strings for example:

```
String[] arr = {"one", "two", "three"};
```

Is possible with Guava Joiner get string like this:

```
"<one>, <two>, <three>"
```

where `,`  is separator and `<` `>` are prefix and suffix for every element.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Joiner with the end of one and the start of the next:

```
Joiner.on(">, <")
```

And then just put a `<` on the start, and `>` on the end.

```
"<" + Joiner.on(">, <").join(arr) + ">"
```

You might want to handle the empty array case, to distinguish this from `{""}`:

```
(arr.length > 0) ? ("<" + Joiner.on(">, <").join(arr) + ">") : ""
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use also Collectors.joining() like below:

```
    String[] arr = {"one", "two", "three"};        
    String joined = Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors.joining(">, <", "<", ">"));
    System.out.println(joined);
```